# Module detail visibility to players on D&D Beyond

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-beyond

So, if I create a *Master Tier* account on *D&D Beyond* I can share the *Monster Manual* and other digital assets with players. If I purchase (say) [Hoard of the Dragon Queen](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/source/hoard-of-the-dragon-queen) on *Beyond*, can the players view all the module details through the interface? Is there any way to limit their access to the module info?

There is a *Compendium Content Only* option on that same page. Exactly where does that fit in? Is that just the content that *should* be shared with the players?

Long time AD&D player, pondering 5th Edition. The digital options are intriguing.

Comment: You'll get a more authoritative answer at https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/d-d-beyond-general/general-discussion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### D&D Beyond's Content Management feature allows DMs to control, to some extent, what content they share with their players.

For a long time, content sharing was all-or-nothing in D&D Beyond. When you had content sharing turned on for your campaign, you shared **all** your purchased content with your players.

However, D&D Beyond now has a "[Content Management](https://www.dndbeyond.com/changelog/575-content-management-initial-release)" feature, where DMs can turn specific books on and off, so that their players can only read the books they want them to be able to read. You can access this feature through the "Content Management" button on your campaign page when you are the DM.

This comes with some caveats, though. If a player owns a book themselves, then of course you cannot prevent them from reading it. Furthermore,

> Blocking a source will hide compendium content to prevent players from
>   reading it unless they own it. No options or content will be removed
>   from other tools such as the character builder, character sheet, or
>   encounter builder.

Regarding the option to purchase a book as "Compendium Content Only:" Purchasing a book as "Compendium Content Only" just means that the book is available to read in D&D Beyond, but the specific content (spells, magic items, classes, races, feats, etc.) from the book is not available for your D&D Beyond character sheets.

Comment: Great. Thanks for providing the details. I can definitely see the draw for reference materials but I think I'll hold back on the modules. Easy enough to share the maps via screenshots if necessary...

Comment: @Omortis Note, this answer has been substantially revised.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I will look into the content management feature - it seems to be just what I was looking for.